# Request for member .. in something not a structure

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, compare

I am quite new to c programming, and i dont know why i am getting the error mentioned in the title. I am trying to write a function which compares the age array from a structure. This is the structure :

```
typedef struct
{
    int index;
    float age;

} index;
```

This is the function, the part of code i am getting the error at:

```
int comp ( const void *a, const void *b)
{
    if ((((index*) a)->age)>(((index*) b->age)))
        return 1;
    else if ((((index*)a)->age)<(((index*)b)->age))
        return -1;
    return 0;

}
```

I was going to use the comp function with qsort. Any ideas why i get this error, please?

Comment: `(((index*) b->age)))` you might want to check your parentheses, keeping in mind that postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators.

Comment: You might want to create separate pointers of the proper type so you're not casting so much.

Comment: Out of that it is a bad idea to use the same name _index_ for a type and for an attribute. I encourage you to always start the name of your types by an uppercase character, so name the struct with _Index_ ... or a better name :-)

Comment: her _comp_ function is called by _qsort_, _qsort_ ask for that signature

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
 (((index*) b->age)))
```

should be

```
(((index*) b)->age))
           ^^^------------------added parenthesis here
```

Otherwise, (*as you might be already knowing*) due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the cast will be ineffective here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, your parenthesis are off here:

```
(((index*) b->age))
```

You can avoid this type of error in the future by creating pointer of the proper type and using those instead of a lot of casts:

```
int comp ( const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const index *a = p1;
    const index *b = p2;

    if (a->age > b->age)
        return 1;
    else if (a->age < b->age)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that no casts are needed here because you can convert freely to/from a `void *`.